# Valet Plus Installation Problems - MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, laravel-valet, valet

I've had Valet Plus installed on my Mac for about 2 years with no problems. Then the other week it suddenly stopped working, I think after upgrading to Catalina, by saying the apcu_fetch() could not be found.

Thinking it was me that had screwed something up, I uninstalled everything to start again, and now I cant install valet again due to pecl not being able to connect via ssl.

Whenever I run `pecl install apcu_bc` it just returns `Connection to 'ssl://pecl.php.net:443' failed`.

Whenever I sometimes get past this part, by installing and uninstalling different versions of php, I then end up back in the same situation of  cant find `apcu_fetch`

I have tried following every single bit advice on the web that references these problems to no avail.

Is anyone else having the same problems and has any new advice please as I am going crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Due to issues with the apcu_bc pecl extension install and growing support for PHP 7.0+ within the apcu pecl extension, deprecate the use of apcu_bc. To ensure new apcu install do the following for every PHP version installed:

Uninstall your pecl installed apcu extensions pecl uninstall apcu && pecl uninstall apcu_bc

Remove the apcu.so and apc.so extensions from /usr/local/etc/valet-php//php.ini